# Random controller inputs

Tags: hardware

Alright, So I have a PowerA wired controller connected to my computer, and I love it to pieces. Works well for all the games I play, and I rarely have any issue with it. That being said, recently I've been having a weird issue where I get phantom inputs when using it with my computer. Sometimes I'll hit L1, and suddenly the game is paused, or I'll use A to jump, and I'll get a B input as well.

I've unplugged the USB and plugged it back in, changing the cable, and changing the port I'm using, and it doesn't seem to fix the problem. I know the controller isn't at fault, as I've plugged it into literally everything else that has an input like that in my house, and don't have the same issue pop up.

The weird part is, for some reason, restarting my entire computer fixes the issue.

I've poked around the forums, as well as reddit and other places, and no one seems to have the same issue I've been having.

Any ideas how to fix this problem? I'm using the latest version of Jammy Jellyfish, if that helps at all.

Comment: Are you even using a current Ubuntu release?  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting